# how to get HiddenField value in separate javascript file [asp.net]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

from aspx file

HiddenField  ID="HiddenField1" value="1"

this is Charting.js (external JS)

```
var b = $("#" + '<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').val();//im not really sure with this

alert(b);//(to test if it work
if (b == "1")
{
    $("#" + a).attr({
        "font-weight": 900
    });

}
```

usually if i do script inside aspx in 1 page i just use

HiddenField1.ClientID

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not necessary that you need to select by id only. You can set a value to class attribute of hidden field and use it to select in js file as following.

```
<input type="hidden" class="myclass" value="myvalue"/>
var b = $(".myclass').val();
```

Comment: never though about using type=hidden on input.since in ASP.net already have asp:hidden, guess this going to work ,thx!